# Why is my closed question not included in my user activity summary and nowhere to find unless using my browser history?

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-delete, activity-tab

I have just edited a closed question. I want to open it once again from the user activity summary menu here at SO meta and cannot find it in the overview when I look at all questions of my user activity tab.

I could only find it back using my browser history.

It is not yet deleted (2 delete votes, perhaps this is relevant?), just closed.

The unfound question:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399946/good-idea-separate-off-topic-vote-option-for-closed-questions-with-a-split-in

Please do not take it as the basis for the voting of this question, this SO meta question here should be held abstract from the SO question.

Comment: That link points to a deleted meta question (deleted 25 minutes ago). It does not match the title of your main question. You have your links mixed.

Comment: That question was trying to do too many things at once. It was closed as unclear, but then you kept trying to use it to undelete a question on main rather than seeking to fix the problems in the question or asking a different one.

Comment: @E_net4 is not funny I have taken time to explain the whole thing again. I then got the idea of trying to reopen the SO question. You can see this in my edits. Trying to undelete the SO question led to the deletion then? Is that an SO rule? And by the way, the SO question was deleted by the same users that were active on SO meta. Deleting an example (!!) had nothing to do with the discussion on meta. So asking those people to undelete is just fair enough.

Comment: @Lorenz it does?  At last!  Allegations of 'herd behaviour' have been made frequently by users who get questions closed/deleted, and I have called them out to provide evidence.  So far, not one valid case has been presented. Some kind of stats analysis would be needed to demonstrate herd and so we need lots of data, you know, data that does not show independent decisions to close/delete bad questions by, for the most part, skilled and experienced developers/curators.  I will look at your questions and, if plausible, add your case to the dataset of >none<

Comment: @Lorenz - The question you wanted reopened was low quality.  **There was no herd behavior from this user.**

Comment: @SecurityHound Apart from you and one other member, there were clear hints that the trusted members have simply downvoted because they did not understand the idea of it. You can see this in the upvotes of wrong comments. You cannot say from this that there was no major herd behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question has been deleted 25 minutes ago by three user votes. Deleted questions are not included in your activity log.